# How to Open/write/close multiple files in a loop?

Tags: python

Example:

```py
f = open (path/pdf1.pdf)
f1 = open (path/pdf2.pdf)
f2 = open (path/pdf3.pdf)
```

Can the above be ran in a loop?

Comment: glob library should come in handy if want to load all pdfs in path or using a prefix like following. 
```from glob import glob;glob('pdf*.pdf')```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all files in a directory with extension .txt in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here is one implementation of a loop (f string needs python 3):

```py
for x in range(1,4):
    f = open(path/ (f"pdf{x}.pdf"))
```

Note that this doesn't do anything with the file though. This also doesn't follow best file practices (really should use a context manager). Can't be more specific without know what you want to do with the file.